# javascript .onchange does not work in IE Edge the first time click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I am having some issue with `.onchange` in IE Edge only.

For uploading files I have this html:

```
<div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="upload_file(event)" ondragover="return false">
    <div id="drag_upload_file">                                                                                                     
        <p>DROP FILE(S) HERE</p>
        <p>or</p>

        <p><input class="browse btn" type="button" value="Browse" onclick="file_explorer();"></p>
        <input type="file" id="selectfile" name="upload" multiple>

    </div>
</div>
```

The javascript:

```
var fileobj;

function file_explorer() {

    document.getElementById('selectfile').click();
    document.getElementById('selectfile').onchange = function() {
      for (var i=0; i< this.files.length;i++){ // multiple files uploading
        fileobj = document.getElementById('selectfile').files[i];
        ajax_file_upload(fileobj);
      }
    };

}
```

What happens: Only in IE Edge, the first time I open the explorer and browse for a file, the file is not "selected". When I open explorer again and choose another file, the file is selected.

**DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/ayw104L7/1/

You can see that IE Edge gives not the alert "file choosen" the first time

Comment: There is a known issue with onchange event and IE, consider adding button with click event of "update"